# htmlentities with ajax editable textarea

Tags: php, jquery, textarea, html-entities

Here is an example of the workflow a user can have on my website :

1. Create a task, with content: I use `htmlentities` to encode the content and store it in my database (yes, I've decided to store the encoded content);
2. The user comes back later and clicks to view the task. The thing is, the preview of the content is done in a disabled textarea.

   - I tried to use `htmlentities_decode` when printing the content in the textarea (XSS problem if the user entered bad things);
   - I just print the encoded text and everything is fine.
3. The user clicks on *EDIT*, this will make the `textarea` editable
4. The user clicks on *SAVE*.

Here is my main issue, as I didn't decode the text before I printed it, it is still encoded and when the user saves it, it is re-encoded. So, the previous content is double encoded.

So, if the first time the user enters something like:

```
blablabla  </textarea/> yeah!
```

Then, it's encoded and the result is:

```
blablabla  &lt;/textarea/&gt; yeah!
```

Then, when I display it, it displays as the user previously entered it but if he saves it, the result is:

```
blablabla &amp;lt;/textarea/&amp;gt; yeah!
```

And, so, if he displays it again, it is not well displayed (and it also takes more and more space in my database as the user keeps editing his task).

Well, I am sure this is a problem a lot of people have experienced but I can't find any good solution.

By the way, I am using `htmlentities` with `ENT_QUOTES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum,
I fixed my problem.
I didn't noticed but for the first entry, I was using htmlentities() and when editing, I was using the Zend escape() function.
Using only htmlentities() fixed the problem. I don't know how the escape() function of ZF works, but I won't use it in the future :p

Thanks you for answers :)

Anyway, so, I am wondering, the htmlentities_decode() function, in which situation should it be used? As I htmlentities() when I get the form and print it like that, I never use the htmlentities_decode(). Is that normal? So I am wondering what is this function used for?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> ahah, here is my main issue, as I didn't decode the text before I
>   printed it, it is still encoded and when the user save it, it is
>   reencoded. So, the previous content is double-encoded.

This is actually correct, you shouldn't *decode* the text before you print it. In fact, it *must* be HTML encoded when output in the HTML page. It is not still encoded when the user submits it because the browser will have already interpreted the HTML entities.

Unless... you are creating a TEXT_NODE in the DOM and assigning the encoded data to this (in the textarea)? In which case the browser will not interpret the HTML entities and you will end up resubmitting already encoded data. Assign to the `innerHTML` property instead, if this is the case. However, the HTML entities would be clearly visible in the form to the end user (on the first edit), before the data is submitted, which does not appear to be the case?